# error psql: warning: extra command-line argument

Tags: command-line

I have Ubuntu 14 server dockerized. All are good I guess, but when I'm going to dump a table:

```
psql -c -h myserver -p5433 mydb -t gr_service_plan_xxx > gr_service_plan_xxx.sql
```

an error occurs:

> psql: warning: extra command-line argument

What does it mean? Am I missing something in the command line?

Comment: Please do not post the same question on multiple StackExchange sites http://askubuntu.com/q/808292/457662

Comment: Question is closed. But it's the one I found when I hit this problem. To fix it I had to use cmd /c <docker cmd> (on Windows) and sh -c <docker cmd> (other platforms) as only the shell program supports pipes. Example http://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the command arguments you included, I think you intended to run `pg_dump` not `psql`:

```
pg_dump -c -h myserver -p 5433 mydb -t gr_service_plan_xxx > gr_service_plan_xxx.sql
```

Or you need to specify the command for `psql`, for example:

```
psql -h myserver -p5433 mydb -c 'SELECT * FROM gr_service_plan_xxx;' > gr_service_plan_xxx.sql
```